# disable swipe gesture that is set on whole screen for mapView fragment, allow only map movement

Tags: android, listview, dictionary, fragment, swipe-gesture

I have a ListFragment and at the footer of the list fragment I added another fragment that contains google map.  I added swipe gestures left->right, right->left to whole Activity and that works fine. The problem is that when user swipes on top of the map it calls left->right, right-left functions. I want to disable these functions for my map view (fragment), and when swipe occurs on map view (fragment) do only map related movements.

If anyone knows how to implement it I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Check this out:  http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-make-android-map-scrollable-inside-a-scrollview-layout/

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet Hi, I tried to implement the code that you suggested, but for some reason it gives me null pointer exception.. Trying to figure out what is wrong. it initiates WorkaroundMapFragment but then it crashes.

Comment: Post the errors from logcat

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet thanks for the link. I combined some code from that article and links from an article and got it working. I got null exception errors because I didn't declare the map fragment correctly in main activity.